# Using Random.Next() inside a function seems biased

Tags: vb.net, random

I wrote a function to randomize a list and got weirdly biased results. Maybe because Random() was instantiated inside the function body. See this simple example and how the results differ. What am I missing? How should I use Random inside a function?

```
    Function testshuffle() As Integer
        Dim rng As New Random
        Return rng.Next(4)
    End Function

    Dim listO As New List(Of String)
    For i = 1 To 100000
        listO.Add(testshuffle.ToString)
    Next

    Debug.WriteLine(listO.FindAll(Function(p) p = "0").Count.ToString, "freq. of 0")
    Debug.WriteLine(listO.FindAll(Function(p) p = "1").Count.ToString, "freq. of 1")
    Debug.WriteLine(listO.FindAll(Function(p) p = "2").Count.ToString, "freq. of 2")
    Debug.WriteLine(listO.FindAll(Function(p) p = "3").Count.ToString, "freq. of 3")
```

the result is:

```
freq. of 0: 30393
freq. of 1: 17924
freq. of 2: 15162
freq. of 3: 36521
```

on the other hand this code:

```
    Dim r As New Random
    For i = 1 To 100000
        listO.Add(r.Next(4).ToString)
    Next
```

results in :

```
freq. of 0: 24743
freq. of 1: 25086
freq. of 2: 25028
freq. of 3: 25143
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is, from your two results it looks like random numbers. Usually, the random class is initialized once and .Next is called multiple time on the same instance. In your first sample, you could set rng as static.

Comment: `listO.Add(r.Next(4).ToString)` results in `0: 24743` ? `Next(4)` returns a number between 0 and 3 inclusive.

Comment: sorry, I thought it is clear from the code. The "Debug.WriteLine(...)" part outputs the frequency of each number from 0 to 3 in 100k runs. There were 24,743 zeros.

Comment: I just edited to make the results more clear

Comment: The documentation for Random on MSDN warns against this quite clearly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new Random` should be outside of the loop and called only once. Otherwise `Random` is intialized with more or less the same seed based on a timestamp.

Comment: adding to that, I've read somewhere that random numbers generated in less than 15ms between eachother contains the same seed. If anyone can confirm this it would be great

Comment: @Gianlucca https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408.aspx - "which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds."

Comment: This is exactly what seems to be the problem here. Another solution is, as noted in the comments, to declare Random as `Static rng As New Random`